# Creating an array, the length of which should be supplied by the user

Tags: arrays

the creation of a vector can be given a number, example:

```
vet int [] = new int vet [100].
```

But if I were to create a program for registration and the user to decide how much, how would I make this entry?

Comment: and which language do you use?

Answer (score 1):

```
int quantidade = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showMessagerDialog(null," digite a quantidade"));

int vet [] = new int vet [quantidade]
```